# ¿Como cambiar el formato de JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

al usar `JSON.stringify()`, obtengo todo el objeto en una sola linea, por ejemplo

```js
const user = {
    'id': '1234',
    'nombre': 'Adam'
}

JSON.stringify(user)
```

Resulta en `{"id":"1234","nombre":"Adam"}`, pero en cambio, yo quiero que resulte algo como

```json
{
    "id": "1234",
    "nombre": "Adam"
}
```

Que metodo podría utilizar para obtenerlo de la manera deseada?

Comment: Eso tienes que hacerlo con JSON.parse(user). El parse es lo contrario de stringify

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quiere es generar un JSON con varías líneas e identación

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const user = {
    'id': '1234',
    'nombre': 'Adam'
}
console.log('Por defecto', JSON.stringify(user));
console.log('Con dos espacios') ;
console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
console.log('Con 4 espacios'); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 4));
```

Como ves, el método `stringify` acepta dos parámetros más, siendo el último el número de espacios para indentar el JSON resultante. Esto implica automáticamente usar nuevas líneas para cada valor.

El segundo parámetro es una función para tratar los datos de un modo "especial" cuando lo consideres necesario, pero se sale un poco del tema de la pregunta, así que simplemente pongo el enlace a la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) por si quieres indagar más.

Comment: Muchas gracias pablo!